# Swap method of Linked List Nodes at Position a and b, stuck on infinite loop in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, infinite-loop

So, I'm trying to solve this question in my book, it asks for a Node swap in a given Linked List at given positions, well, I've tried implementing a method called "swap" and it gets stuck on an infinite loop, and I can't figure why

here's the method:

```
    public void swap(LinkedList L1, int start, int end) {
    Node ptr1, prev1, ptr2, prev2;

    ptr1 = head;
    prev1 = ptr1;
    int count1 = 0;
    int count2 = 0;
    if ((start <= size()) && (start > 0) && (end <= size()) && (end > 0)) {
        while (count1 != start && ptr1 != null) {
            prev1 = ptr1;
            ptr1 = ptr1.link;
            count1++;
        }
        ptr2 = head;
        prev2 = ptr2;
        while (count2 != end && ptr2 != null) {
            prev2 = ptr2;
            ptr2 = ptr2.link;
            count2++;
        }
        prev1.setLink(prev2.link);
        ptr2.setLink(ptr1.link);
        prev2.setLink(ptr1.link);
        ptr1.setLink(ptr2.link);
    }
}
```

and here's the main method, that I've trying to test the method in:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList L1 = new LinkedList();
    L1.addToStart(5);
    L1.addToStart(7);
    L1.addToStart(23);
    L1.addToStart(56);
    L1.addToStart(52);
    L1.addToStart(22);
    L1.addToStart(57);
    L1.addToStart(99);
    L1.addToStart(34);
    L1.addToStart(74);
    L1.outputList();
    L1.swap(L1, 2, 4);
    L1.outputList();
```

Comment: your code doesn't make sense: you have `LinkedList L1` arg that is never used, and something called `head` that is nowhere defined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not linking things correctly. You make both ptr2 and prev2 link to ptr1.link.

Assume this is the list

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

and we want to switch B and E.

```
prev1 = A
ptr1  = B
prev2 = D
ptr1  = E
```

Relinked, it looks like

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
|-------------------^
     |-------------------^
          ^---------|
      ^--------|
A -> E -> C -> D -> B -> F
```

In code:

```
Node temp = ptr1.link;
prev1.setLink(ptr2);
ptr1.setLink(ptr2.link);
prev2.setLink(ptr1);
ptr2.setLink(temp);
```